# Applying function to whole table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a function that takes as input "id" and "startdate" and then returns a value.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fp_v2.fp_spinoffadjprice (id CHAR(8), startdate DATE)
RETURNS FLOAT

BEGIN

DECLARE splitadjprice FLOAT;
DECLARE spinofffactor FLOAT;

SELECT fp_v2.fp_splitadjprice(id, startdate) INTO splitadjprice;

SELECT fp_v2.fp_spinofffactor(id, startdate) INTO spinofffactor;

RETURN splitadjprice*spinofffactor;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I then have a large table with columns:

```
ID        DATE
```

The function basically takes the ID, Date From this table and extracts the Price from another table and calculates an adjusted price.

My final output should therefore be a table with:

```
ID        DATE         Price        Adj. Price
```

How would I possibly do this ?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the function code as well. Some sample table data and expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: `select myfunction(id, date) from mytable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `select`:

```
select t.*,
       function(id, date) as function_value
from bigtable t;
```

Comment: I would like to note that if you have multiple calls, make sure to put the abbreviation inside the function. Forexample function (t.id, t.date).